# c# : Is it possible to user DropDownList of an .aspx page in DropDownList of GridView of other page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu

I am having DropDownList with country name list in my .aspx page and on other page I need the same DropDownList with same data but in GridView.

Is it possible to use that DropDownList ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a user control that contains this behavior and then you can this user control in several places.

Comment: +1 - Creation of a custom user control is the way that I'd go.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. just create another dropdown box and fill in the same database data in the dropdown inside the gridview.